# Did Marisol and Mesquite have to collaborate to levitate?

Tags: ingrid-law, scumble

In Scumble, by Ingrid Law, it seemed that the sisters Marisol & Mesquite O'Connell always worked together when using their *savvy* to levitate objects. Was this a requirement? And furthermore, if so how could they accomplish this?

What seems particularly challenging if they had to work together is how they could mix their *dual* individual intentions when they had to control *three* axes of motion. This sort of implies they each could control only a portion of the levitation impulse, and yet somehow combine the effect together.